# Modificar el lenguaje para las consultas en tipo de dato datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM REGULARIZACION WHERE FECHA_CORTE = '2019-12-31'
```

Al ejecutar la consulta me muestra el siguiente error:

> La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor
>   fuera de intervalo.

Para resolver el error ejecuto el la consulta:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH 
SELECT * FROM REGULARIZACION WHERE FECHA_CORTE = '2019-12-31'
```

Mi duda es si existe una manera de configurar el servidor para que por default me tome las consultas de las fechas en formato `LANGUAGE ENGLISH` ?

Comment: Ya encontré la respuesta y es de la siguiente manera: `ALTER LOGIN sa WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar desde SQL Management Studio entrando a las opciones avanzadas en las propiedades del servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como también lo puedes realizar directamente modificando las configuraciones del servidor, indicando el `langid` para ello utiliza la siguiente consulta `sys.syslanguages`

por ejemplo:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Vi que resolviste tu duda, mientras investigaba encontré como referencia [Esta Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106812/1545868).
También puedes cambiar ese parámetro desde el **SQL Server Management Studio**, 
En la parte de Security - Logins, seleccionar el usuario que esas usando para hacer los querys y le das Propiedades. Seleccionas el idioma en "`Default Language`". Hacer lo mismo con algún otro usuario que haga consultas.